# Rails : ajax call failed to get data from backend

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am trying to get a drop down data from a route.

I made the dropdown data a model.

```
create_table "choices", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string "description"
    t.datetime "created_at", null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
end
```

and I seed it as following:

```
Choice.create!(
  [
    {
      description: "Choice 1"
    },
    {
      description: "Choice 2"
    }
  ]
)
```

This drop down model does not have its own controller, it is used by another model's api controller. The model looks like

```
  create_table "forms", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.text "username"
    t.datetime "created_at", null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
  end
```

And this is how "Choice" Model is used in the form's controller

```
class Api::FormsController < ApplicationController
  def choices
    all_choices = Choice.all.
                map {|e| {"label" => e.description, "value" => e.id}}.as_json
    respond_to do |format|
      format.json { render json: all_choices, status: :ok }
    end
  end
end
```

I also create a get route for that model

```
constraints(lambda { |req| req.format.symbol.in? [:json, :csv, :xlsx] }) do

  post '/login' => 'sessions#create'

  namespace :api, defaults: { format: :json } do
    get '/forms/choices' => 'forms#choices' 
  end
end
```

and from my front-end(Using React)

```
getDropdown(){
  ajax({
    url: `/api/forms/choices.json`,
      dataType: 'json',
      success: data => {
        this.setState({
          choices: data
        });
      },
      error: () => {
        console.log("Error retrieving data")
      }
    })
}
```

When I use `console.log(this.state.choices)` to print out the data I got, I got empty object. I am relatively new to rails and understand that it is convention over configuration, so I believe I am missing something small here.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: When you execute `getDropdown`, does the request reach the `choices` method (you can tell that from logs)?

Comment: I believe so, because I do see choice.json in the Network tab.

Comment: I would try something like this: add `binding.pry` (you have to add `pry` and `pry-rails` to your Gemfile) in the `choices` method, execute the ajax call from the console, manually. Then, if it reaches `choices`, `binding.pry` will stop code execution and you will be able to debug this issue.

Comment: thanks, I will look into that

Comment: ok, I tested it by putting a puts statement and the choice method in my controller is actually never called. I also put a byebug in the function and it was never executed as well, so you are right. Do you have any idea why

Comment: I tried to replicate your issue (with the same routes, controller) but I used jQuery to send ajax call. Everything worked as expected. Have you tried to call the javascript method from the console, manually? In my case it works as expected.

Comment: I found out the problem, it is super weird, i cant explain why, feel free to comment it, I am going to edit my answer.

Comment: Just post the answer. It might help others

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The explanation is simple. You have the following route:

```
get '/forms/:user_id' => 'forms#show'
```

So, it will match:

```
/api/forms/1
/api/forms/2
```

But it also matches:

```
/api/forms/otherstuff
/api/forms/some_string
/api/forms/choices
```

In general, you should read your route as:
match `/api/forms` and then, if there is anything else added to the route, treat it as a `:user_id`.

This is described in the Rails documentation:

> Rails routes are matched in the order they are specified, so if you have a resources :photos above a get 'photos/poll' the show action's route for the resources line will be matched before the get line. To fix this, move the get line above the resources line so that it is matched first.

Source: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#crud-verbs-and-actions

Answer (score 0):

The problem is my route. There are other routes before the `choice` route in fact.

```
constraints(lambda { |req| req.format.symbol.in? [:json, :csv, :xlsx] }) do

  post '/login' => 'sessions#create'

  namespace :api, defaults: { format: :json } do
    get '/forms/otherstuff' => 'forms#otherstuff'
    get '/forms/:user_id' => 'forms#show'   <----
    get '/forms/choices' => 'forms#choices' <----
  end
end
```

I fixed it by switching the `choice` route with the route above it, just simply switched their places and it worked.

```
constraints(lambda { |req| req.format.symbol.in? [:json, :csv, :xlsx] }) do

      post '/login' => 'sessions#create'

      namespace :api, defaults: { format: :json } do
        get '/forms/otherstuff' => 'forms#otherstuff'
        get '/forms/choices' => 'forms#choices'  <----
        get '/forms/:user_id' => 'forms#show'    <----
      end
    end
```

I have no idea why, I would love to get a explanation of this rail behavior

Comment: The routes are followed in order. The first route that matches will be followed. So `forms/choices` will match `forms/:user_id` with `user_id=choices` (that there is a "better" route lower in the routing does not matter anymore).